# Сократить код из множества

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Можно ли как-нибудь объединить такой код, что бы им не спамить? Код использую для включения чекбоксов по получаемым данным каждой марки авто. Т.е. из бд вывожу список авто, формирую массив из чисел, потом через js нахожу чекбокс.

```js
var arr = $.parseJSON('<?= json_encode($bmw)?>');
arr.forEach(function(arr) {
  $('input[att=bmw][value=' + arr + ']').attr('disabled', false);
});

var arr = $.parseJSON('<?= json_encode($audi)?>');
arr.forEach(function(arr) {
  $('input[att=audi][value=' + arr + ']').attr('disabled', false);
});

var arr = $.parseJSON('<?= json_encode($lada)?>');
arr.forEach(function(arr) {
  $('input[att=lada][value=' + arr + ']').attr('disabled', false);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно например так:

```js
var obj = {
  bmw: [1, 2, 3],
  audi: [4, 5, 6],
  lada: [7, 8, 9]
};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key =>
  obj[key].forEach(item => console.log(`input[att=${key}][value=${item}]`)));
```